# Multi-level sub-menu JSON in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a some records in the table having parent child relations, screenshot below:
[image]

How do I write a JPA Entity to retrieve those records with respect to Parent-Child relation. Your help is appreciated.

The code that did not help me well is as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = PlatformConstant.TABLE_MENU)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Menu implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
   private String url;

   @Column(name = "description")
   private String description;

   @Column(name = "qr_code")
   private Blob qrCode;

   @JsonManagedReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   private Set<Menu> children;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonBackReference
   private Menu parent; 
}
```

> My code above has the following wrong output:
>   [image]

Using the JpaRepository find all, and applying the answer from @lucid, the new output is as below:

the code:

```
@Autowired
private MenuService menuService;

@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/all")
@ResponseBody
public List<Menu> getMenus() {
    return (List<Menu>) menuService.findAll().stream()
             .filter (menu-> Objects.isNull(menu.getParent()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

the output:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jackson` provides these annotations to control the parent-child relationships.

> @JsonBackReference: skips property during the serialization process
>
> @JsonManagedReference: forward reference and serialized annotated property

In your case, you don't want `parent` object to be serialized inside your child reference, you can annotate it with `@JsonBackReference`

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Menu> children;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
private Menu parent;
```

Now, to remove child objects from response, we can filter that 
Like this

```
menuService.findAll().stream()
     .filter(menu-> Objects.isNull(menu.getParent()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it works, but there is a little issue in the result

Comment: [
{
"id": 7,
"url": "",
"description": "main menu 1",
"qrCode": null,
"children": [
{
"id": 9,
"url": "url.......",
"description": "child menu 2",
"qrCode": null,
"children": []
},
{
"id": 8,
"url": "url...",
"description": "child menu 1",
"qrCode": null,
"children": []
}
]
},
{
"id": 8,
"url": "url...",
"description": "child menu 1",
"qrCode": null,
"children": []
},
{
"id": 9,
"url": "url.......",
"description": "child menu 2",
"qrCode": null,
"children": []
}
]

Comment: id=7 being retrieved fine with its two children. But the problem is that the children are also explicitly coming in the result.

Comment: unable to use StringUtils.isBlank method. Where it is to be imported from?

Comment: `Objects.isNull(menu.getParent()).collect(Collectors.toList());`
there's an error: **Cannot invoke collect(Collectors.toList()) on the primitive type boolean**

Comment: the question is updated. (updated the entity and the controller method)

Comment: yes it says: Cannot invoke collect(Collectors.toList()) on the primitive type boolean

Comment: there is compile time error over this line: `.filter (menu-> Objects.isNull(menu.getParent()).collect(Collectors.toList()));`